# HZ432 and no heat in one zone

Tags: central-heating, zoned-heating

I have 4 zones... The following lights are on the HZ432:

- Heat 1 - red
- Heat 2 - red
- Heat 3 - no light
- Zone 1 - yellow
- Zone 2 - red
- Zone 3 - red
- Zone 4 - red

I have heat in 3 zones, but not in one of the zones....no blowing from the vents

We have 2 TRANE XV 80 Units - one is on and the other has no activity
What do these lights mean?

Comment: That's that wireless Honeywell controller, that thing can be a nightmare. Do you have zone dampers in the duct? This one might be tough to fix over stack exchange unless you have pretty good technical knowledge about the system. Can you take pictures of the wiring?

Comment: My furnace has little levers at the beginning of each duct coming out of it.  The lever opens or closes the air flow through the duct.  If yours does too, you could check that they're all open.

Comment: @JoeFala, It's a zone controller that supports wireless devices, but its main job is controlling dampers and the equipment based on the input of multiple thermostats.  Because of how complicated they are I wouldn't attempt any wiring troubleshooting remotely.  There's no good standard on wire colors and the wires are almost never labeled (is that damper 1 or 2?  What thermostat does that come from? etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image from the [installation manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.supplyhouse.com/manuals/1249544725953/Honeywell_HZ432_Install_Guide.pdf) of your zone controller:

[image]

The fact that Heat 1 and Heat 2 are red means that some combination of thermostats is calling for stage 1 and stage 2 heat.

The lights on the zone are pretty easy to read as well.  A red light means that damper should be closed (no air to that section) and a green (might look yellow) light means that zone should be open (have air flow).

Now, the light pattern you describe means that *if* everything is wired correctly and all the dampers are functioning, you should have air in Zone 1 only.  The red zones should be closed and not have air.  However, there are two types of dampers - normally opened and normally closed, and they have to be wired differently so the controller knows how to open them.  If this is a new installation or work has been done recently, it could be wired incorrectly.

If a damper fails, the unit *could* show a blinking amber light, but it depends on how it failed.  Some types of failures the controller cannot sense.  It's possible that two zones are stuck open so the controller thinks that only one is open, but really there are 3 open.

If you read the manual for the controller, there are ways to test each damper and cause the fan to run.  You can cycle through each zone one at a time to make sure the dampers work and are wired correctly.  Those instructions are on page 13 in the section named "Checkout".  I would have gone with "Testing" or "troubleshooting", but they picked "Checkout"...  I forget if it allows this or not, but be sure not to close all 4 dampers with the fan running.  The air pressure could blow out some duct joints or damage the dampers.

As far as the activity of your two Trane units - this zone controller is *designed* to have one unit hooked up to multiple zones.  It's not made to control multiple units.  There *might* be a way to use the various heat and cool "stages" to control multiple units, but then you're really getting into advanced territory.

If you do call in some outside help on this, do what you can to make sure they are very well versed in these zone controllers.  I had two A/C people give me incorrect information on how they work and really struggle to identify a problem with the system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you normally have a light on heat 3 because with two furnaces you should only have two stages of heat unless one is connected as a two-stage and one is connected single stage. So heat 1 shows one furnace is receiving a call for heat and Heat 2 shows that the other furnace is receiving a call for heat.

I would check to make sure both furnaces are running and if so check to make sure that all the dampers are working properly.

If one furnace is off it may suggest there's a problem with the furnace. In that case I would troubleshoot the furnace ignoring the Honeywell system.

To do that simply disconnect the R terminal in the furnace and use a jumper wire to go from R to W.

Alternatively you could check to see the status of the Furnace through a little window in the bottom door there should be a flash code cross reference the flash code with the chart documented in the manual.

Comment: Do note that "two stages" and "two furnaces" are not interchangeable, and this zone controller is not specifically designed to control two separate furnaces.

Comment: @JPhi1618 agreed the only thing I can think of is the system is being utilized in a way not intended by Honeywell. Unless there is more the system not disclosed by the OP

Comment: Ha, yea, it may well be controlling both furnaces. What I was cautioning against is if that is the case we have no idea what “should” happen because someone made it up.